# Llamar método de otro modelo desde la maquina de estado

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando llamar un método desde la maquina de estado desde el modelo `Compra.rb` para poder realizar una acción después de que la compra cambie de estado.

El estado por defecto de la compra es `"nueva_compra"`, al cambiar de estado pasa a `"inventario"` y luego realiza un acción con el método `:after => :charge_stock`

**Modelo Compra.rb**

```
class Compra < ActiveRecord::Base
    include AASM #Maquina de estado

    has_many :item_compras, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_compras,
    reject_if: RejectDeeplyNested.blank?,
    :allow_destroy => true


    aasm column: "state" do
        state :nueva_compra, :initial => true
        state :inventario

        event :inventariar do
            transitions :from => :finalizadas, :to => :inventario, :after => :charge_stock do
            end
        end
    end

    private


end
```

**Modelo ItemCompra.rb**

```
class ItemCompra < ActiveRecord::Base
    include AASM

    belongs_to :compra
    belongs_to :product

    private

def charge_stock
    inventario = self.product.stock + self.cantidad_bidon
    self.product.update!(:stock => inventario)
end

end
```

¿Cómo puedo llamar al método `charge_stock` del modelo `ItemCompra` desde la maquina de estado con el método `:after`?

Me gustaría poder recibir la ayuda necesaria respecto a esto, ya que me parece una forma segura de cargar el stock de productos al sistema.

Utilizo la gema: [AASM](https://github.com/aasm/aasm).

Comment: Me imagino que quieres correr el método `charge_stock` para todos los objetos `ItemCompra` que pertenecen a la `Compra`; ¿es correcto?

Comment: Sí, es como lo hacia antes, pero quiero utilizar la maquina de estado de la compra para realizar la acción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes definir un método de `Compra` el cual ejecute `charge_stock`; por ejemplo:

```
aasm column: "state" do
  state :nueva_compra, :initial => true
  state :inventario

  event :inventariar do
    transitions :from => :finalizadas, :to => :inventario, :after => :charge_stocks
  end
end

private
def charge_stocks
  item_compras.each do |item_compra|
    item_compra.charge_stock
  end
end
```

En este caso el método se llama `charge_stocks`, y dentro de este método se iteran todos los objetos de `ItemCompra` relacionados ejecutando `charge_stock` de la clase `ItemCompra`.

Para que funcione es necesario que el método `charge_stock` de la clase `ItemCompra` sea **público**:

```
class ItemCompra < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  belongs_to :compra
  belongs_to :product

  def charge_stock
    inventario = self.product.stock + self.cantidad_bidon
    self.product.update!(:stock => inventario)
  end

  private
  # métodos privados
end
```